# Skipping single item in a sorting method

Tags: android, arrays, sorting

I'm having an issue while i'm looking to sort my Variables to fees Menues, i mean i have an ArrayList with data as "WITH PEPERONI,1," or "CHAMPAGNE,1,2," where ,1, or ,1,2, means the menu of the variable so when i press on Menu 1 i have to see only variables that had ,1, or ,1,2, or ,1,2,3, (where there is 1) in their array.

And actually what i've done works but only with variables that has multiple menues i mean if a variable is in menu 1,2,3,4 and i press on 2 that will be visible but if the variable is just in one menu as 1 so ,1, in array that will be not visualized and i can't get why.

here is my code where i filter the variables and set them in a new Array:

```
 public void FilterVariable() {

        filteredVariable = new ArrayList<>();

        for (VariantiConstructor varianti : variantiConstructors) {
            String data = varianti.getMenu();
            String[] items = data.split("," + positionMenu + ",");

            try {
                if (items[0].equals(data)) {
                  //
                } else {
                    filteredVariable.add(varianti);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //
            }


        }

    }
```

While here is a screen from where i was debugging and where there was a ,2, and it skipped it insteam of adding in the ArrayList:

[image]

Comment: to print exception logcat then move on with solution

Comment: Exception is not giving errors

Comment: please need to print the exception like e.prinStackTrace();

Comment: e.printStackTrace();

Comment: so i have just to add 
e.printStackTrace(); under catch {? cause it's not giving any result

Comment: @JohnKarry Please check the solution below, I have just given the idea of it..Check it and let me know in case of concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following code for the shorting the `ArrayList`

```
 ArrayList<String> YOUR_ARRAYLIST = new ArrayList<>();

    private void searchDataFromList(String serachString) {


        ArrayList<String> SEARCH_ARRAYLIST = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < YOUR_ARRAYLIST.size(); i++) {

            if (serachString.contains(YOUR_ARRAYLIST.get(i))) {
                SEARCH_ARRAYLIST.add(YOUR_ARRAYLIST.get(i));
            }

        }
    }
```

On your click listener, u need to call this `searchDataFromList()` method as following

```
YOUR_CLICK.setOnClickListener(view -> {

    String searchString ="WITH PEPERONI,1,";
    String YOUR_SEARCH_STRING ="";

    List<String> YOUR_SELECETD_LIST = Arrays.asList(searchString.split(","));
    for (int i = 0; i <YOUR_SELECETD_LIST.size(); i++) {
        if (YOUR_SELECETD_LIST.get(i).length()==1)
        {
            YOUR_SEARCH_STRING = YOUR_SELECETD_LIST.get(i);
            System.out.println("VALUE IS ==>>>>> "+YOUR_SEARCH_STRING);
        }
    }

    if (!YOUR_SEARCH_STRING.isEmpty())
    {
        searchDataFromList(YOUR_SEARCH_STRING);
    }
```

Comment: Okkay now it's work's reverse, it's adding now just items that have only one menu so if a variable have menu ,1, another ,1,2, another ,1, another ,1,2,3,  the added variables are just one with ,1,

Comment: maybe i just have to put in searchString the number of the menu without comas?

Comment: @JohnKarry ..Is it workable for u..Let me know in case of concern

Comment: Actually by inverting YOUR_ARRAYLIST.get(i).getMenu.contains(searchString) worked thank you.

Comment: so now the method is "     filteredVariable = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i= 0; i< variantiConstructors.size(); i++){
            if(variantiConstructors.get(i).getMenu().contains(search)){
                filteredVariable.add(variantiConstructors.get(i));
            }
        }" and it's working fine